# FluentValidation: Must clause is ignoring the When clause and running regardless

Tags: c#, asp.net, fluentvalidation

I'm using FluentValidation in my project. There is an issue that the `Must` clause is ignoring the `When` clause. Below is a code sample.

```
RuleFor(model => model.Field)
  .Must(somePredicate)
     .When(conditionToRunValidation)
```

But the `Must` clause ignores the `When` and gives error even when the `conditionToRunValidation` is `false`.

I'd be grateful for any sort of guidance to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to work, so probably your condition is not `false`. You should try debugging your code and check if `conditionToRunValidation` really is `false`, or post more of your code, where you set the value of it.